# Random number from range using C

Tags: c

I have a big problem , I do not understand.

I need to generate random numbers from the interval.

I am using code:

```
unsigned int nahodnyCisloZIntervalu(unsigned int min, unsigned int max) {
    int r;
    const unsigned int range = 1 + max - min;
    const unsigned int buckets = RAND_MAX / range;
    const unsigned int limit = buckets * range;

    do {
        r = rand();
    } while (r >= limit);

    return min + (r / buckets);
}
```

But every time you start the program generates the **same** numbers!

How to generate truly random numbers usnig `C`?

Comment: Whats wrong with standard  functions ?

Comment: How true must *truly* be?

Comment: Vote to reopen as this could be a question on "how to generate true random numbers in c".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function. It is normal that `rand` returns the same sequence each time.

Use the [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) function at the beginning of your program in order to initialize the random number generator with a "seed", using for example the current time as seed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this code not working for interval.      `srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % 6;` (interval 0-6), if i run in while() i get a same numbers.

Comment: @criagoug You must use `srand(time(NULL))` only _once_ at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Oh, ok, now it's working, thank you.

Comment: @criagoug also read [this quite comprehensive SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159644/using-rand-to-generate-a-random-numbers).