# c++ random set seed failed

Tags: c++11, random

I am trying to set seed to the c++ std::default_random_engine:

```
#include<random>
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


void print_rand();


int main() {

for (int i{0}; i < 20; ++i) {
    print_rand();
}
return 0;
}

void print_rand() {
    default_random_engine e;
    e.seed(time(0));

    cout << e() << endl;
}
```

It seems that the printed numbers are same, how could I set the seed to generate the random number according to the time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using rand to generate a random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159644/using-rand-to-generate-a-random-numbers), same issue of seeding every call.

Comment: @Kit. Yes, the printed time(NULL) is the same each time.

Comment: @Kit.Why will time(0) give me the same value each time?

Comment: Because the time _in seconds_ is still the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @P.W. said, you should seed only once. A minimal change in that direction would be using a static variable with the seed given to the constructor:

```
#include<random>
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>

void print_rand();

int main() {
    for (int i{0}; i < 20; ++i) {
        print_rand();
    }
    return 0;
}

void print_rand() {
    static std::default_random_engine e(time(0));

    cout << e() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to seed only once instead of every time the function is called. Then you will get different values. I will move the functionality to `main()` to demonstrate this.

```
#include<random>
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::default_random_engine e;
    e.seed(time(0));

    for (int i{0}; i < 20; ++i) {
        std::cout << e() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jQuocRxX8jrdo9R0)

Comment: What if I do not have a main? I am actually writing some python extension, then I have no main function.

Comment: That's just an example I have given to demonstrate the right behavior. The point is you have to **seed only once**.

Comment: Hi, will the seed be set for the whole process. If I set the seed in some function, will the settings still work after the function is returned?

Comment: Yes, you can have a static variable inside the function that you seed only once.