# How do you create pseudo random numbers sequentially in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, random, time, seed

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (it=hand.begin(); it < hand.end(); it++)
    (*it) = rand() % 13 + 1;
```

This code does not work to create many random numbers at a time.
Is there a way to do it that isn't as complex as Mersennes and isn't operating system dependent?

Comment: I think this sentence *"This code does not work to create many random numbers at a time"* ....is not clear enough!

Comment: Duplicated many times. You only seed (i.e. call `srand`) ***once***. Then you just call `rand` over and over again. Essentially all PRNG work that way.

Comment: Where's that xkcd? ... [Ah! :)](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: @pmg: This [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/221/)?

Comment: I just realized I posted the code wrong! I'm not seeding rand more than once. I'm seeding it once and then when generating many random numbers in a row they all come out the same because they're based on the current second.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859089/always-repeated-numbers-given-by-rand Near duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068350/random-number-function-is-misfiring and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3159644/2509

Comment: @Dash: srand() is called ONCE. Put it in main. Call it on entry and never touch it again. As long as your application is not called more than once a second you will not repeat the numbers for the next 60 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PRNGs don't create many PRNs at once.  Each output is dependent on the previous output, PRNGs are highly stateful.

Try:

```
srand(time(NULL)); // once at the start of the program

for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    r[i] = rand();
```

Even APIs that return an entire block of output in a single function call, have just moved that loop inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Call `srand` just once, at the start of your program. Then call `rand()` (*not* `srand(rand())`) to generate each random number.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_random.html) has lots of good random number generators which are easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

George Marsaglia posted a [Multiply With Carry PRNG](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/3a300062dd866485) some time ago in sci.math.

I cannot say how good it is or how well it behaves, but you might want to give it a try.

It should be OS and platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

"please make sure you answer the question"
OK

```
for (int i=n1; i < n2; ++i)
  { 
  int k; 
  do k = rand(); while (i !=k); 
  // k is a sequential pseudo random number
  }
```

There may be issues with efficiency...